# Android DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android, dex

I'm getting the infamous `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` bug. That would mean I've reached the maximum number of methods. But I don't think that that is the problem, because the last time I got this error (a couple of days ago) I just recreated my project (with the exact same classes) and the error no longer appears...

... but now it's back!

Is there any other reason for the appearance of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "That would mean I've reached the maximum number of methods" -- no, that would mean that you have reached the maximum number of method references, which usually comes as a result of attaching from lots of third-party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @CommonsWare. Still, does that explain why the error disappeared (for a couple of days) when I recreated the project from scratch?

Comment: That I cannot explain. It is conceivable that you were right on the edge of the limit, and your work since the re-creation pushed you back over the edge.

Comment: If you have not already done so, clean the project (Project > Clean Project in Android Studio, Project > Clean in Eclipse). Pre-compiled stuff from before you removed the libraries might still be floating around and perhaps contributing to the problem.

Comment: Ok, after some cutting on libraries and module dependencies, the problem disappeared. So it was probably the number of method references that was causing it. Thanks, @CommonsWare, for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution will use proguard also for debug assembly. Add in Gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```